# Set dialog box window class name

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, atl, wtl

What's the proper way to subclass a dialog so that its class name will change to a specified one, so it would be later found with FindWindow (from another process)?

```
class CMyDialog : public CDialogImpl<CMyDialog, CWindow> {
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_MAIN };

    // error: CDialogImpl doesn't support GetWndClassInfo
    DECLARE_WND_CLASS(L"unique class name") 
};
```

Comment: Did you try to get the dialog handle by specified window name?

Comment: @Mykola: what do you mean by "window name", window class or window title? If the former then I simply cannot set a unique name this way. If the later then the problem is that the title can change, or I cannot modify the application that does the FindWindow search.

Comment: In any way class will not be unique as the window title (name) .

Comment: @Mykola: how is that? The process searches for a unique GUID class name, which is guaranteed not to collide with other applications unless they wish their window to be found by that process. The window title, on the other hand, changes depending on multiple factors, like application name, internationalization, current UI state, etc...

Comment: Dialogs have a fixed class name, that cannot be changed (without breaking anything anyway). If you need to identify your window from another process, you can attach additional data to it by calling [SetProp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633568.aspx). Specifying the string representation of a GUID for *lpString* enables a process to uniquely identify a window.

Comment: @IInspectable: I suspect that this is actually possible. I look at `CIndirectDialogImpl`, `CMemDlgTemplateT` and `DLGTEMPLATEEX`. The later has a `windowClass` field. It feels like subclassing `WC_DIALOG` should be achievable.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but not without breaking the dialog manger's functionality.

Comment: @IInspectable: I'm not sure what do you mean by "dialog manager" functionality, there isn't really such thing in Windows. The way dialogs work is by an interplay of different pieces of the API, which are, apparently, all customizable to a great extent.

Comment: [The dialog manager, part 1: Warm-ups](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050329-00/?p=36043) through [The dialog manager, part 9: Custom accelerators in dialog boxes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050408-41/?p=35943). There really is such a thing as the *dialog manager*.

Comment: @IInspectable this is how specifically Raymond calls this part of the API. But this term is nowhere to be used by the official [API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Which is logical, because all those separate pieces of functionality are not a separate entity as the term "manager" would suggest, unlike [DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: You are right, *"dialog manager"* is not official terminology. There is, however, a distinct subsystem (built on top of the window manager - also not an official term), that implements dialog specific features, for example [IsDialogMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498.aspx) (see also [Why do we need IsDialogMessage at all?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120416-00/?p=7853)). All those features could be implemented using the window manager only, [but it's hard to get right](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040227-00/?p=40463).

Comment: @IInspectable: this is right, but I was not talking about implementing all of those. On the contrary, what I was asking, and the solution I found, is how to override the window-class name without disturbing any of the functionality. This works because functions like DefWndProc or IsDialogMessage do not rely on the WC_DIALOG class.

Comment: This is not entirely true. The Edit Control tries to detect, whether it's in a dialog or a regular window. All the ugly details are covered in [Just because you’re a control doesn’t mean that you’re necessarily inside a dialog box](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070820-00/?p=25513). The way the Edit Control detects that it is hosted in a dialog is likely to break, when changing the window class to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some additional search I found [How to provide your own Window class name for an MFC dialog box](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251059). There is nothing MFC specific though.

In summary:

- Add `CLASS "your class name"` field to the dialog resource. It can be done from within the GUI: disable MFC Mode on the resource file properties, then Class Name property appears in the dialog properties.
- Subclass the WC_DIALOG class as follows:

  ```
  WNDCLASSEXW wc;
  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  ::GetClassInfoExW(0, WC_DIALOG, &wc);
  wc.lpszClassName = "your window class";
  wc.style &= ~CS_GLOBALCLASS;
  ::RegisterClassExW(&wc);
  ```

Extra reading: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100215-00/?p=14943/